# Choosing the intervals

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

The game consist of two sequences of integers `A of length N and B of length M`, and it will last for exactly `M` turns.

In the i-th turn, the corresponding player should select an interval (continuous subsegment) of sequence A of length `Bi` that is strictly inside the interval selected in previous turn, i.e. if the interval in previous turn was `[l,r]` then if the interval in current turn is `[u,v]` then it should satisfy `l < u ≤ v < r`, except in the first turn where the player can select any interval of length B1.

For the Odd turns we added the sum of all number in range [L,R]( Start with 1 turn) for even turn we subtract all numbers in range [L,R].

What will be the maximum score ? If both player play optimally.

For Example:

```
A=3 7 5 4 9 6 1 3
B= 6 3 1
```

- chooses the interval [1, 6] (i.e. (3, 7, 5, 4, 9, 6)). The score now
  is 34 points.
- In the next turn,  chooses the interval [3, 5] (i.e. (5, 4, 9)). The
  score now is 34 - 18 = 16 points.
- In the next turn,  chooses the interval [4, 4] (i.e. (4)). So finally
  score of the game is 16 + 4 =20.

This is the score of the game when both player play optimally.
How to determine the optimal score ?

Comment: Is this game referenced somewhere ?